# Custom Transparent Shader rendering order is wrong on iOS

Tags: unity, shaders, ios

In Unity Engine, I wrote a custom transparent shader(I use blend to achieve) for crystal effect and it's totally fine on Windows. However, when it's on iOS platform, the crystal always culls everything so that if a wall is on the front of the crystal, you still can see the crystal while on Windows you only see the wall.

I tried to change ztest to Greater, on Windows if something culls the crystal it will render so it's what I want while on iOS, the crystal will never render.

Comment: I wrote two passes, one should be "RenderType=Transparent" but I didn't write anything in this pass and another is "RenderType = TransparentCutOut". However, I wrote a global "RenderType = TransparentCutOut". Then, the issue comes.

Comment: Don't put your code in the comments. Edit your question so you can show us the minimal, complete code that lets us reproduce the issue, and you'll get better code formatting too. :)